# iOS: Setter not setting @property— getting error: No visible @interface for 'Xviewcontroller'-- some of the time?

Tags: ios, properties, segue, getter-setter

Okay guys and gals— this one is throwing me for a tail spin. I am trying to pass the value of a string to a property on another class — which we can call CreateViewController.h/m

There are several view controllers that have a value for that string that can set it and so far one of them is successful in doing so, but for two of the other classes that try to set the property with

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"create"]){
        CreateViewController *pvc= [segue destinationViewController];

       [pvc setString: String];
    };
```

I get the error "No visible @interface for 'CreateViewController' declares the selector 'setString:'"

but like I said— one of my classes does this same exact setting method and it works! the String is passed in and "CreateViewController" gets it.

Just so you can see the setup in the header file of the CreateViewController the code for the property is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* String;
```

I have no idea what Xcode's problem is.

Thanks for your help in advance!

EDIT: So after some testing, I found out that not only can it not see this one property that we called String, but won't see any properties on the header file (I tried making some new properties and setting them). I have imported the header file at the top of all the classes so it really doesn't make any sense. I can even segue to the screen— I just can't set the value!

**EDIT 2**: Not sure what's going on now, but after I tried compiling the app, in the header file of the CreateViewController, I get told that

```
@interface CreateViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

is a "Duplicate interface definition for class 'CreateViewController' ." I don't see anything before or after that defining it. Now I'm really banging my head against the wall.

Comment: Is error "@interface for 'CreateViewController' declares the selector 'setString:"? That seems not an error.

Comment: sorry about that it should read: "No visible @interface..."

Comment: `#import <CreateViewController.h>`

Comment: @BryanChen If you are referring to importing with #import "CreateViewController.h" in the other classes that set the string for "CreateViewController.h"— I have done that, but the error is still popping up.

Comment: You should `@`+hisname when you talk to him or he will not be noticed.

Comment: @KudoCC- thanks for the tip. As you can tell I'm new to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Okay so here was the problem. Xcode, being a sneaky little bugger, had some corrupt copies of

CreateViewController.m
CreateViewController.h

in the same folder as the working copies. Thus the setters didn't know what to set because the corrupt files didn't have anything in them to set.

Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear:

In order for this to work, the CreateViewController class needs to have a public property defined in it's header file called "string". Not "String", but "string".

Instance variable and property names should start with a lower case letter.

The setter for a property  string is named setString. The setter capitalizes the first letter of the property name.

Then you need to #import the CreateViewController.h file in any .m file that tries to reference the properties or methods of the CreateViewController class. Make absolutely sure that you're importing the header file in the .m file that contains the prepareForSegue code you posted.

Comment: although it was working with the capital letter, I changed it and it still didn't work. What is really baffling is that one of the ViewControllers is able to set the value with no problem— exactly copied letter for letter the same way. All the view controllers have #import "CreateViewController.h" at the top. Only one is able to set it.